# Visual studio,C#:Saving current state of application and recovering it

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, saving-data

I'm building windows forms application using c#.Is there any "easy" way of saving current state of application on closing and then restoring it's state on opening? I want application to look exactly the same as it did when I closed it, and I also would like to avoid saving all elements one by one.

Comment: Yes, build an ApplicationState class where you store all the needed informations and then store this to a file (maybe as JSON). On startup load the file and set your application according to the data in ApplicationState

Comment: There are plenty of ways to do such a thing, starting from using the settings file, though using a database, and ending with creating your own custom file. You need to supply more details on what exactly you want to save if you want a good answer.